# Combine aggregation pipelines with update operators

Tags: mongodb

I would like to aggregate different `measurements` into a single document acting as a bucket. I receive individual measurements in this format:

```
[
  {
    "datetime": "2020-08-03T08:00:01.648475Z",
    "celsius": 20.7,
    "humidity": 57
  },
  {
    "datetime": "2020-08-03T08:05:07.756834Z",
    "celsius": 18.9,
    "humidity": 58
  }
]
```

The aggregated bucket should look like this:

```
{
  "_id": "2020-08-03",
  "celsiusHigh": 20.7,
  "celsiusLow": 18.9,
  "firstMeasurementAt": "2020-08-03T08:00:01.648475Z",
  "lastMeasurementAt": "2020-08-03T08:05:07.756834Z",
  "humidityHigh": 58,
  "humidityLow": 57,
  "measurements": [
    {
      "datetime": "2020-08-03T08:00:01.648475Z",
      "celsius": 20.7,
      "humidity": 57
    },
    {
      "datetime": "2020-08-03T08:05:07.756834Z",
      "celsius": 18.9,
      "humidity": 58
    }
  ]
}
```

Since MongoDB 4.2 I can make use of [Aggregation Pipelines](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/). However, these pipelines support only the stages `$addFields`, `$set`, `$project`, `$unset`, `$replaceRoot`, and `$replaceWith`. I would like to use other update operators, such as `$setOnInsert` (to set fields only once - upon insertion), `$currentDate` (to set e.g. `lastUpdatedAt`), or `$addToSet` to set some of the bucket's fields. Without `$addToSet` the operation looks quite verbose:

```
{ $set : { "measurements": { $setUnion : [ { $ifNull: [ "$measurements", [] ] } , [ { "datetime": "2020-08-03T08:05:07.756834Z", "celsius": 18.9, "humidity": 58 } ] ] } } }
```

Is there a possibility to combine aggregation pipelines with update operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update operators only support structure manipulation of a single object at a time so you can't achieve the result you want with them.

But what you can do is have an aggregation pipeline utilizing [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {$ArrayElemAt: [{$split: ["$datetime", "T"]}, 0]},
            celsiusHigh: {$max: "$celsius"},
            celsiusLow: {$min: "$celsius"},
            firstMeasurementAt: {$min: "$datetime"},
            lastMeasurementAt: {$max: "$datetime"},
            humidityHigh: {$max: "$humidity"},
            humidityLow: {$min: "$humidity"},
            measurements: {$push: "$$ROOT"}
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "collection_name"
    }
]);
```

Note that this is under the assumptions all `datetimes` are saved under the same format / timezone. without this it can't be done.

Comment: Thank you Tom, I'll have a look at `$out`. Is it possible to use it in an upsert/update statement, though? It looks like I would need to have an additional collection for the measurements and aggregate them into the buckets collections. I am searching for one atomic command which adds measurements to the buckets directly - as I won't need them in their original structure afterwards.

Comment: `$out` does what you want as it will overwrite the collection thus "deleting" all the old documents. there is no other "atomic" alternative. anything else will require at least 2 db calls.

Comment: I will definitively check it out, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.